# Row level security in looker studio

Tags: looker-studio, data-studio-custom-visuals

I have a dataset and dashboard which will be accessed by multiple people in my company, each person has a role assigned to them e.g ELT , Directors , Managers. Now what I want is that when a person from ELT opens the dashboard they have ALL the data available on the dashboard. When a director opens the dashboard they only have their clients feedback data available to them and for managers only their programmes feedback data.

I have looked at various videos online and they all apply row level security by applying a filter on the dashboard.

This is the structure of my data (a lot more other fields as well)

```
client  programme_name  client_poc  First name  Last name   Email   internal_poc_1  internal_poc_2  Overall, how satisfied are you with your experience with the company?   Any feedback
```

This is the structure for my Managers sheet

```
User    Email   Client  Programme_name  Role
```

the programme_name is joined with the programme_name in my data sheet and then I apply a filter on email to only display programme data to the managers they are assigned the programme to.

Now I have two more conditions , the ELT team should have access to all the data not just the programme

```
User    Email   Role
```

And the directors

```
User    Email   Client  Role
```

should have access to their client's data only.

I can apply row-level security on manager level only. Not sure what's the best way to apply the security on ELT and directors level

The only thing I can think of is to add as many rows as there are rows as there are in my dataset for each of the ETL level person so they have access to ALL the programmes data and the same for Directors. My data is stored in Google sheets.